# Растянуть картнику на экран телефона с сохранением пропорций картинки, чтобы длина была 100vh(по длине экрана), а ширина не сжималась

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, bootstrap

Растянуть картнику на экран телефона с сохранением пропорций картинки, чтобы длина была 100vh(по длине экрана), а ширина не сжималась. У меня картинка 1920 1080, она просто вытягивается, и смторится ужасно

Comment: Код в студию!) 
Можно вписать в родительский контейнер, можно задать h:100vh, w:auto. Но тогда она "вылезет" справа. Если bg, там ещё вариантов можно накинуть.

Answer (score 2):

1. У экранов нет "длины". Судя по vh, вы имеете в виду высоту.
2. если картинка в теге `<img>`, то так:

   ```
   img {object-fit:cover;}
   ```

   (контейнеру при этом нужно будет задать какую-нибудь высоту и ширину, лишь бы не было auto)
3. если  картинка - фоновое изображение, то так:

   ```
   .myImage {background-size: cover;}
   ```